# Mori domain if and only if every $v$-ideal is of finite type?

Tags: commutative-algebra

In commutative alebra, I proved that in a Mori domain, every $v$-ideal(divisorial ideal) is of finite type. But converse is hard to me..I don't know it's correct. Someone help me plz

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to go slightly further and show that in a Mori domain, every $t$-ideal is of finite type.  The argument that finite-type $t$-ideals imply Mori is simple, and essentially the same as the argument in, say, Noetherian iff ACC on all ideals.  The important observation here is that

> a union of a chain of divisorial ideals is always a $t$-ideal, in any domain.

Note that finite type $t$-ideals is enough to force the $v$-operation and $t$-operation to coincide.

In general, finite type $v$-ideals is not nearly enough to force a domain to Mori.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! Is $R=\mathbb{Z}+X\mathbb{Q}[[X]]$ an counterexample?. I know $R$ is not a Mori, but it's difficult to find $v$-ideal of $R$